# October CMS | In Models/Model_Name/fields.yaml, how do I use select: to concatenate but remove characters when the column I select is null

Tags: mysql, sql, octobercms

This sounds much more complicated than I have made it out to be.

So I have something like this already in my fields.yaml:

```
select: concat(id, ' ', ' - ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' - ', business_name)
```

The problem here is I would end up with something like this when there is no business field:

```
1 - Michael Angelo -
```

Is it possible to replace the ' - ' with '' when there's no business name selected.

I hope this makes sense and it's probably more of an SQL question than an October one but any help would be great.

Comment: What is the value of `business_name`: is it `null`, or an empty string?

Comment: In some circumstances it may have an empty string depending on whether it has been entered and other times not. Ultimately, it’s only a cosmetic issue but a frustrating one.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most ideal solution, but I have gone with something like the following:

```
select: concat(id, ' | ', IF(char_length(`business_name`)>0, `business_name`, 'N/A'), ' | ', first_name, ' ', last_name)
```

This gives me the following outcome if business_name has not been entered:

```
1 - N/A - Michael Angelo
```